# Weird white border inside of image when it should be transparent

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I have this code:

```
public class Main {
  private BoardHandler boardHandler;

  Main() {
    Display.setTitle(Cons.WINDOW_TITLE);
    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(Cons.SCREEN_WIDTH, Cons.SCREEN_HEIGHT));
        Display.create();
    }
    catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, Cons.SCREEN_WIDTH, Cons.SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0, 1, -1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    boardHandler = new BoardHandler();

    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Clock.update();

        // game:
        boardHandler.update();

        Display.update();
        Display.sync(60);
    }
    Display.destroy();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
  }

}
```

I load textures using this function:

```
public static Texture loadTexture(String path, String fileType) {
    Texture tex = null;
    InputStream in = ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(path);
    try {
        tex = TextureLoader.getTexture(fileType, in);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return tex;
}
```

I draw stuff with this function:

```
public static void drawTile(Texture tex, float x, float y, float radius) {
    tex.bind();
    glTranslated(x - radius / 2, y - radius / 2, 0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2d(0, 0);
    glVertex2d(0, 0);
    glTexCoord2d(1, 0);
    glVertex2d(radius, 0);
    glTexCoord2d(1, 1);
    glVertex2d(radius, radius);
    glTexCoord2d(0, 1);
    glVertex2d(0, radius);
    glEnd();
    glLoadIdentity();
}
```

I draw these images: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Llqw.png

And get this as a result: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCWu3.png

The X'es are drawn the exact same way as all the other tiles, yet the X'es has these ugly white borders around them. Do note that these white borders are "inside" of the image I'm trying to draw. The blackness inside the white borders is the background showing through like how it's supposed to look.

What is the problem? Why are the white borders present when those parts are transparent in the image? Is there a solution to this?

This is my first attempt at using any 2D/3D engine to draw stuff, I'm just searching for a quick fix if possible.

Comment: Random thought: have you tried using the wrap mode `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`? If that helps, I can write up a more detailed explanation for you.

Comment: Like I said, I don't have any prior experience with openGL so I don't know what GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE means, much less how to use it. The code presented is pretty much taken straight from a tutorial, just some slight modifications. A more detailed explanation would be appreciated, however I don't want to delve too deep since I'm pretty much just testing the waters as of right now.

Comment: And for the guy who edited my post. Thanks, but there where more images than one in each of the links. 
http://imgur.com/4IZO9CC,gmpPfMM,gF1EeBs,nrv6NRR,OwLgHoM,wfGvAvr,CVEagHD,6ij24M4,pheIjuI#0
http://imgur.com/pgExbTE,liEJ01d#0

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! It seems like openGL (or at least the way I set it up) does not like semi-transparent images for some reason. All I had to do in order for the white borders to disappear was to make every pixel in the image either fully transparent or fully opaque.